# mongoose Missing schema error while populating

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

I am building an app with express using mongoose as ORM for my MongoDB database.

I have 2 models located in separate files : User and Posts.

User.js model looks like

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    moment = require('moment'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    UserSchema = new Schema({
        created_at: {type: Date, default: moment()),
        name: String
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

and the Posts.js model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    moment = require('moment'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    PostSchema = new Schema({
        created_at: {type: Date, default: moment()},
        user: {type: Schema.Type.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
    });
```

I call them in controllers in separate files that looks like

```
var Post = require('../models/User'),
    User = require('../models/Posts');

Post.find().populate('user').exec();
```

This population returns me a MissingSchema error that says :
MissingSchemaError: Schema for model 'Posts' hasn't been registerd.

The connection to the database is in the main file : app.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/database');
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: `var Post = require('../models/User'),  User = require('../models/Posts');` - names are the wrong way around. Also you registered with `mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);` using `'user'` in lowercase and your ref is `"User"` in uppercase. Those need to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your reference is for "`User`", I think you just have to declare your first model with correct Typpo

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

instead of

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('user', UserSchema);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I have changed that but still does not work, I have everything as @Buu97

Comment: Open a question with your code example, I can try to help you

Comment: Thank you @Sparw,  it seems that that same conflict can happen with GraphQL with cyclic dependencies but already solved, thanks!